# AbstractMethodError when creating typed query with Hibernate 3.6.3 and JPA 2.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I'm using Hibernate and JPA for a small project.

Somehow when trying to obtain an typed Query, the

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery
```

is thrown; org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl is from hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar .

This is not okay throwing the above exception:

```
  public Account read(Account entity) {
        EntityManager em = ManagedEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();

        String jpql = JPQLGenerator.readAccount();
        TypedQuery<Account> typedQuery =
                em.createQuery(jpql, Account.class);
        typedQuery.setParameter("accountId", entity.getAccountId());
        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
```

This is okay, however:

```
public Account read(Account entity) {
    EntityManager em = ManagedEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();

    String jpql = JPQLGenerator.readAccount();

    Query query =
            em.createQuery(jpql);
    query.setParameter("accountId", entity.getAccountId());
    Account account = null;
    Object obj = query.getSingleResult();
    if(obj instanceof Account) {
        account = (Account)obj;
    }
    return account;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have quite a mix of Hibernate and JPA versions.  In subject line you mention  Hibernate version 3.6.3 and JPA version 2.0. According body text EntityManagerImpl is version 3.3.2.GA. This mesh up with versions causes your problem.

[TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) was introduced in JPA 2.0 and Hibernate implements this specification since 3.5.X. Now you have [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) interface with

```
<T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery)
```

but actual implementation does not implements such a method. That's why you get AbstractMethodError. Your second query works fine, because it uses JPA 1.0 constructs with one of the it's implementations (3.3.2.GA.) Just use implementation from Hibernate version 3.6.3 (or better even never).

Comment: Cannot put enouth information in a comment so I have given another answer.

Comment: I have put hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.3.jar but now I get another exception (earlier): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError      Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.  Persistence.xml looks loke:

Comment: I cannot post another answer (not enough reputation) and I do not have enough space for posting the persistence.xml file so I will put a link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27959140/persistence.xml

Comment: Your persistence.xml have at least these problems: 1)xmlns and version attribute missing from persistence-element, 2) .connection.pool_size should have value-attribute and no value for element, 3) you haven't defined persistence provider, you need something like:<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> (depends which you want to use). From http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html you can find example persistence.xml Because your original question got answered, you can accept this answer and create new questions for next problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have managed to make the tests pass with the new hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.3.jar but they are still failing when I am trying to obtain the TypedQuery.

Comment: Then you still have trash in your class path, because from the code you can see that method is there: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.3.Final/org/hibernate/ejb/AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java#AbstractEntityManagerImpl.0entityManagerSpecificProperties