# java.lang.AbstractMethodError during createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to retrieve a list of results from my database, by following an example in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354639/5655414) Howeverm, I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
```

Here is my code, to denote how I am calling this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class CoolsEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "Decimal(10,0)")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "COOL_GUY_NAME")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

This code below generates the error:

```
final String sql = "select c from CoolsEntity c";
final TypedQuery<CoolsEntity> query = em.createQuery(sql, CoolsEntity.class);
final List<CoolsEntity> results = query.getResultList();
return results;
```

However, if I do something like this, I can see the results:

```
final String sql = "select c from CoolsEntity c";
final Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<CoolsEntity> results = query.getResultList();
return results;
```

All of the references to em are imported through this package:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

Shouldn't the two queries above generate the same result? Am I missing a cast to the List interface to allow this to work in the typed query?

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860181/abstractmethoderror-when-creating-typed-query-with-hibernate-3-6-3-and-jpa-2-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an `AbstractMethodError` exception which is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.
You have quite a mix of Hibernate and JPA versions.

`TypedQuery` was introduced in `JPA 2.0` and Hibernate implements this specification since `3.5.X`

**Suggesstion :** Use implementation from Hibernate version `3.6.3` (or higher).

Comment: ah, I see. My hibernate is on version 3.4. Since I am bound to this version, is there no alternative?

Comment: Check this http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ you need JPA 1.0 version for hibernate 3.2+ till 3.5+.

Comment: Ah, I am bound to JPA 2 :/ I have to keep it on 2.

Comment: Then you have to move on to hibernate 3.5+ (3.6+ will be good). I guess there should not be any issues with this change for you.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably using two differnet version of interface `EntityManager` and  implementation `EntityManagerImpl`.

Comment: is there a good way I can confirm that these two are different?

Comment: with your IDE, search tje jar that containes `EntityManager` and the jar thar containes  `EntityManagerImpl`.